# How do I define an instance method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to define a method called `function`. It works when I do this:

```
a = A.new

def a.function
   puts 100
end
```

But I want the method to work for *any* instance variable, not just `a`. For example, when I call `function` on an instance of `A` other than `a`, nothing happens. So I used `A::f` to define the function rather than `a.function`.

```
class A
    attr_accessor :function
    attr_accessor :var
end

def A::function
    self.var = 0x123
end

a = A.new
a.function

puts a.var
```

This compiles fine but when I try to call the function I get an error. Why is it not working and how can I do what I'm attempting?

Comment: Have you tried looking at an introductory Ruby tutorial? This should be in, like, chapter 1.

Comment: I've edited your title since otherwise it may confuse people (as it seems to have confused @GabrielePetronella. You want an instance method I think, not to define a method on a class (that would be a class method, and it's a whole different thing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're *really* tangled up here. I suggest you check out [_why's poignant guide to ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/book/chapter-2.html) and get a handle on what is going on here.

As an attempt to steer you right, though…

- `a` isn't an *instance* variable. It's a local variable that you're using to reference an *instance* of `A`.
- `def a.foo` defines a method on the eigenclass of `a`.
- `attr_accessor :function` already defined `A#function` (that is, an instance method on `A` called `function`) that essentially looks like this: `def function; @function; end`
- `def A::function` defines a class method on `A` that you could access via `A.function` (not an instance of `A` as in `a.function`.
- MRI doesn't really *compile* ruby like you might anticipate. It runs it, dynamically interpreting statements in realtime.

You *probably* want to stick with defining standard instance methods in the traditional manner, and avoid using “function” as a placeholder name since it is a reserved word and has special meaning in other languages. I'll use “foo” here:

```
class A
  def foo
    'Awww foo.'
  end
end
```

That's it, you can now create an instance of `A` (`a = A.new`) and call `foo` on it (`a.foo`) and you'll get back `'Aww foo.'`.

Comment: Or, if you don't find _why's completely idiosyncratic style fun, maybe check out [Ruby in Twenty Minutes](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart) at [Ruby-lang.org](https://www.ruby-lang.org).

Answer (score 5):

```
class A

  def function
    puts 100
  end

end

a = A.new
a.function #=> "100"
```

That's a classic instance method. Is that what you're looking for or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to define methods dynamically, you could use [Class#define_method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method). Otherwise, if you are just wanting to define the method for the class, defining it in the scope of class A will suffice.

Anyway, could you be more specific on what are you trying to accomplish and what kind of error you're having, please?